# I use react-native-popup-dialog and I get some warns

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-dialog

I installed react-native-popup-dialog and I use it. I get the same warn when I enter the page with the component or when I open the popup dialog. Can you help me?

The error: "Warning: Failed prop type: Prop 'children' has type 'any' or 'mixed', but was not provided to 'PopupDialog'. Pass undefined or any other value"

```
<Dialog
  visible = {this.state.addVisible}
  rounded
  width = {0.85}
  dialogAnimation={new SlideAnimation({
      slideFrom: 'bottom',
    })}
  footer = {
    <DialogFooter>
      <DialogButton
        onPress = {() => {}}
        textStyle = {styles.buttonText}
        text = "Add"
      />
      <DialogButton
        onPress = {() => this.setState({addVisible: false})}
        textStyle = {styles.buttonText}
        text = "Cancel"
      />
    </DialogFooter>
  }
>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to issues:

> It's type warning. `children` is required for `DialogContent` component.

Please add that like this:

```js
<Dialog
    visible={this.state.visible}
    onTouchOutside={() => {
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    }}
  >
    <DialogContent>
      {...}
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
```